# Selenium Web Driver - How to get all the items in case a page load element at the run time while scrolling down?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am tired of solving an issue where I need to get the products from a web page. The products load only when the user scroll the page downwards. Each time on a scroll 12 elements are loaded. There is a class applied on this page known as infinite-scroll.

Page URL: http://www.marksandspencer.ie/Dresses/IE_SubCategory_1002041,en_IE,sc.html

I coded the below but is not getting the output.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Scroll {

    @Test
    public void f() {
        FirefoxProfile p = new FirefoxProfile();
        p.setPreference("css.enabled", false);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(p);


        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://www.marksandspencer.ie/Dresses/IE_SubCategory_1002041,en_IE,sc.html");
        WebElement itemCount = driver.findElement(By.className("innerTD2"));
        String a = itemCount.getText();
        int num = Integer.valueOf(a);
        System.out.println("item count ="+a);
        for(int i=0;i<num/12;i++)
        {
            JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
            jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)", "");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to test if 12 new elements will load if you scroll down? Does your script work?

From your code I see that you are selecting class "innerTD2" which is actually one  element. If I understand this right, you need to access the DIV element inside this TD and get the text from there. You should be able to get that text by calling:

```
 String divXpath = "//*[@id='search']/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div";
 String resultshits = driver.findElement(By.xpath(divXpath)).getText();
```

Comment: No I am trying to load all the elements by scrolling down till all the elements are there on the page. Than I want to extract the data for all the elements. I am getting stuck to scroll the page till all the elements are loaded on the page.

Comment: Is your script not working? I just tried this call in my selenium test, and it works as expected. maybe your problem is that the page does not have a real end, but always gets extended. In that case, maybe you should scroll down for a fixed number of pixels (using "scrollBy"), and then check the number of elements.
This worked well in my selenium test:

    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);");